# Liquid - Passing a 'section' variable to be printed on 'snippet'

Tags: liquid

I have a variable in my section which I would like to be printed in one of my snippets. How do I go about it?

Example:

```
Section name = 'pricing_option'
Variable name = 'section.settings.price_name'
```

I would like to pass the above variable to my snippet `'course_card'` which is then to be printed. How do I achieve this?

[Screenshot of Section code 'pricing_options'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiQqQ.png)
[Screenshot of Snippet code 'course_card'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02Ysf.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in shopify, you should use RENDER. They deprecate INCLUDE:

your_section.liquid

```ruby
{% assign price_name = section.settings.price_name %}

{% render 'your_snippet',  price_name:  price_name %}
```

done you can use `price_name` inside your snippet

Other platforms continue to use INCLUDE. INCLUDE not require declare the variables, the snippets are included in the concern of the parent section. means:

your_section.liquid

```
{% assign price_name = section.settings.price_name %}
{% assign cool_stuff = section.settings.cool_stuff %}

{% include 'your_snippet' %}
```

your_snippet.liquid

```
<p> Here you can see {{ cool_stuff }} or {{ price_name }} </p>
```

Be careful because the snippet will see all the variables from the section and this can cause bugs.

Other option is use WITH. it pass a value to the snippet as a variable with the same name of the snippet.

```
{% assign price_name = section.settings.price_name %}

{% inlcude 'your_snippet' with price_name %} 

{% comment %} 
  this is valid too 

  {% inlcude 'your_snippet' with section.settings.price_name %} 
{% endcomment %}
```

at your_snippet.liquid

```
<p> my price name is {{ your_snippet }}</p>
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, however there is an error in compiling. I have added screenshot images above ^

Comment: witch version of liquid you use? the syntax is different for shopify or jekill.

Comment: It is Liquid code builder on Thinkific. It didn't state the version. But I suspect the version does not support the render tag. Is there a work around?

Comment: Render is a new word in Shopify liquid, Thinkific should use include there is more easy to use. In the section use `{% include your_snippet %}` and you should has access to the sections variables.

Comment: the include tag will cause my section look weird as it include other parts of my snippet in too

Comment: try `{% include your_snippet  with price_name %}` WITH is a little special, inside the snippet the variable has the name of the snippet file instead of price_name. this article should be pertinent for you https://www.shopify.ca/partners/blog/88186566-tips-for-using-snippets-in-your-shopify-theme

Comment: where should I add this include tag exactly?